# Array of array of array to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to convert my array of array of objects to array of objects.

I would like to merge two data into one.
I have a data holder which is an array

```
const dataholder = ["itemCode","item","cashier"];
```

and a data that needs to map in `dataholder` key

```
const record = [
        {
          itemCode: { value: 1},
          item: { value: 'Pen'},
          cashier: {value: 'Sam'}
        },
        [
          itemCode: {value: 2},
          item: {value: 'Eraser'},
          cashier: {value: 'Kim'}
        ]
    ];
```

I have tried this code below but it the result turns to array of array of array

```
record?.map( item => {
        return dataholder ?.map( (field) => {
            return {
                [field]: item[field]?.value
            }
        })
    })
```

and here's the output

```
       [
        [
          {'itemCode': 1},
          {'item': 'Pen'},
          {'cashier': 'Sam'}
        ],
        [
          {'itemCode': 2},
          {'item': 'Eraser'},
          {'cashier': 'Kim'}
        ]
]
```

expected result

```
[
        {
            itemCode: 1,
            item: 'Pen',
            cashier: 'Sam'
        },
        {
            itemCode: 2,
            item: 'Eraser',
            cashier: 'Kim'
        }
    ]
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: have you tried using flatMap instead of map?

Comment: What is the purpose of `dataholder` (the "quantity" key makes things extra confusing) here and what do you mean by "merge"? To me, it looks like you just want to remove the object values in your `record` objects.

Comment: dataholder are the one who control on what to get in the record data

Comment: @sinned so why is the `cashier` key in your output when it is not in `dataholder` array?

Comment: @NickParsons sorry twas a typo on dataholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your `record` objects, and for each object, map over your `dataholder` array to create an array of `[key, obj[key].value]` arrays. This will result in your inner `.map()` creating an array of the form ...

```
[[key, value], [key2, value2], ...]
```

... for each object (`obj`) that is iterated on by your outer `.map()`, where the value is obtained from the `obj`. You can then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert this array of key-value pair entries into an object:

```js
const dataholder = ["itemCode","item","cashier"];
const record = [ { itemCode: { value: 1}, item: { value: 'Pen'}, cashier: {value: 'Sam'} }, { itemCode: {value: 2}, item: {value: 'Eraser'}, cashier: {value: 'Kim'} } ];

const res = record.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(
  dataholder.map(key => [key, obj[key].value])
));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
record?.map(item => {
  const obj = {}
  for (const key in item)
      if (dataholder.includes(key))
        obj[key] = item[key].value
  return obj
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, in the inner loop, you could use `reduce`

```
const res = record.map((item) => {
  return dataholder.reduce((acc, field) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [field]: item[field].value,
    };
  }, {});
});
```

```js
const dataholder = ["itemCode", "item", "cashier"];

const record = [
  {
    itemCode: { value: 1 },
    item: { value: "Pen" },
    cashier: { value: "Sam" },
  },
  {
    itemCode: { value: 2 },
    item: { value: "Eraser" },
    cashier: { value: "Kim" },
  },
];

const res = record.map((item) => {
  return dataholder.reduce((acc, field) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [field]: item[field].value,
    };
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way (using `.map` combines with `for... of`)

```
var result = record.map(r => {
  var item = {};
  for(let key of dataholder)  item[key] = r[key].value;
  return item;
});
```

```js
var dataholder = ["itemCode","item","cashier"];
var record = [
        {
          itemCode: { value: 1},
          item: { value: 'Pen'},
          cashier: {value: 'Sam'}
        },
        {
          itemCode: {value: 2},
          item: {value: 'Eraser'},
          cashier: {value: 'Kim'}
        }
    ];
var result = record.map(r => {
  var item = {};
  for(let key of dataholder)  item[key] = r[key].value;
  return item;
});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @sinned Does this answer your question? Don't forget to give me an upvote if that makes sense ^^!